# Execution Time of Command Line Command

Tags: java, linux, debian

I am trying to compare two tools execution time, which I have installed in my Debian Linux server. Now, I have to give two command line command to execute those two tools.

For example say,

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

and

```
cat file4 file5 file6 > file7
```

Now, I want to find execution time of 1st and 2nd command.

Can anybody help me, how to find those two commands execution time? Programmatically foundation (say in Java) is also acceptable.

Comment: Use the [`time` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)).

Comment: Why would a question like this be down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `time` command

```
time cat file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

`time` will write it's output to `stderr`, so the redirection doesn't hurt.

Comment: Yes; 0.03s were spent in `cat`. The system (the kernel) used 4.04s (open files, copy data). The elapsed time is user + kernel + time spent in other processes (it's the difference between the time when the `time` command was started and when it finished) or waiting for some I/O (harddisk, network, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Linux [time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) command ?

From the `man` page:

> The time command runs the specified program command with the given
>   arguments. When command finishes, time writes a message to standard
>   output giving timing statistics about this program run.

Note that shells often have a built-in time command as well, so this may cause confusion. If you want the command as opposed to the built-in (likely to be more fully featured), then the easiest way is to specify it via the full path.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -o timing_info {my command}
```

(for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got another. "time -f "%e" command". Outputs only command execution time in seconds. In my case, 5.65.